# Adding the contact details from the app to the iPhone Contacts using Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift, contacts

Can anyone help in adding the contact from the app to the iPhone Contacts using Swift? I found some helpful code in Objective C but it would be great if anyone can provide guidance in Swift.

I am able to add the contact successfully with the below code. But I like to open the contact app of the iPhone and should be able to see/ edit/ save the details or the fields, before it actually saves and shows the alert 'contact added successfully' . Any slight help is much appreciated.

```
func addToContact()
{
    var firstName : NSString = "Name"
    var phone : NSString = "1234567890"
    var err : Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    var addressRec : ABAddressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err).takeRetainedValue()

    var contact : ABRecordRef = ABPersonCreate().takeRetainedValue()

    ABRecordSetValue(contact, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, firstName, &err)

    var phoneNumbers : ABMutableMultiValueRef  = returnMultiStringRef()
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumbers, phone, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, nil);

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressRec, contact, &err)

    var success : Bool = ABAddressBookSave(addressRec, &err)

    if(success)
    {
        println("added")
    }
    else
    {
        println(" not added")
    }



}

func returnMultiStringRef() -> ABMutableMultiValueRef {
    let multiStringProperty: NSNumber = kABMultiStringPropertyType
    return Unmanaged.fromOpaque(ABMultiValueCreateMutable(multiStringProperty.unsignedIntValue).toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSObject as ABMultiValueRef
}
```

Comment: Please include [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) in your post.

Comment: @milo526 - I have added the code which I have done, I am able to add the contact successfully with this code. But I like to open the contact app of the iPhone and should be able to see/ edit/ save the details or the fields, before it actually saves and shows the alert 'contact added successfully' . Any slight help is much appreciated. Thank you